# Can I run LUA scripts on AzerothCore?

Tags: azerothcore, eluna-lua-engine

I wanted to know if we could use some LUA scripts with AzerothCore?

I didn't found answers by googling "AzerothCore LUA script" or "AzerothCore LUA engine"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, AC Support lua. You have to install it, check this link
https://github.com/azerothcore/mod-eluna-lua-engine

Answer (score 2):

Ok it seems I found the answer since there's a module that allow to make Eluna compatible with Azerothcore 
(https://www.azerothcore.org/modules-catalogue/details.html?id=131435473)